# bcrypt.comare always returns false

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, bcrypt, mongodb-atlas

I have a node.js app which uses express, mongodb-mongoose, passport , bcrypt etc. i have set up 2 databases one local and one on mongodb atlas. at my local database i can register and login but when i try it on atlas i can never login even though i am registered

(route) admin.js

```
adminRouter.post('/register',async (req,res)=>{
    const user = new User({
        username:req.body.username,
        password:bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password,10)
    })

    try{
        const savedUser = await user.save();
        res.json(savedUser);
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    
})
```

passport.js

```
module.exports = function(passport){
    passport.use(new localStrategy({usernameField:'username'},(username,password,next)=>{
        User.findOne({username:username}).then(user=>{
            if(!user){
                return next(null,false,{message:'The username does not exist'});
            }
            console.log('incorrect password' + password +'user.password'+ user.password);
            bcrypt.compare(password,user.password,(err,isMatch)=>{
                console.log('incorrect password' + password +'user.password'+ user.password)
                if(err) throw err;
                if(isMatch){
                    return next(null,user)
                }else{
                    console.log('incorrect password' + password +'user.password'+ user.password)
                    return next(null,false,{message:'password incorrect'})
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(err=>console.log(err));
    }))
    passport.serializeUser(function(user,next){
        next(null,user.id);
    });
    
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id,next){
        User.findById(id,function(err,user){
            next(err,user);
        });
    });
}
```

in the console it is being logged :

```
incorrect password<password>user.password<password>
incorrect password<password>user.password<password>
incorrect password<password>user.password<password>
```

Comment: To me sounds like a conflict in the connection configuration to your databases. You said it's working locally, which means your code is always connecting to the local database, therefore the user cannot be found in your Atlas database.